# Installing GCC in mac

Tags: gcc, macports, installation

I've recently installed gcc 4.6.3 on my MAC (with OSX Lion, XCode 4.3, gcc 4.2.1). I've made a folder named my_gcc463, which contains all files after compiling gcc with make command, etc.
I've also installed MacPorts to select between all versions of gcc that I have. The problem is when I run this command:

```
port select --list gcc
```

I can't see the new gcc 4.6.3 in the list so that I can select that. Also when I run this command:

```
sudo ln -s -f ~/my_gcc463/gcc-4.6.3 /usr/bin/gcc
```

to link gcc to the one I want, It's not working. For example after creating that symlink, when I run:

```
gcc -v
```

It doesn't give me the version. What should I do to make my new gcc appear in the gcc list? Did I do anything wrong? Should I install it in other way?

Thank you in advance for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

`port select` is a tool to maintain the gcc installations from MacPorts and, if available, the versions provided by Apple. Although you could hack it up by dropping your own descriptions into `/opt/local/etc/select/gcc`, I would recommend a different approach for this.

To achieve what you want you should modify your PATH environment variable to include the new path to your gcc version at the front, such that `gcc` resolved to the correct absolute path.

Assuming your new `gcc` binary is at `~/my_gcc463/gcc`, you should add the following to your .profile/.bash_profile or .bashrc:

```
export PATH=~/my_gcc463:$PATH
```

After setting this up, run `gcc -v` in a new terminal window to check if it is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much!
It worked perfectly, now I can see the new version.